# egrep regex operation not working as expected

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a file with content as such:

```
[TEXT_ID=2]
[TEXT_REV=3]
[NO_OF_BYTES=16]
0010002$%!003000040000000010100
[TXT]
FF FF
[TXT_ID=2$@]
[TXT_REV=3]
[NO_OF_BYTES=17]
0010002003000040000000010100
 [TXT]
 FF FF
$%^&
```

I want to identify anything other than `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> as a junk character.

I have to however make sure that a `=` or `[` or `]` when comes as a part of `[CONTEXT=val]` line, will be a valid character. However if it comes in any other line then will be an junk character.

For example in the 9th line of my file if comes any `=`, `[` or `]`, it is junk:

```
0010002003000040000000010100=[
```

So I'm using the below:

```
egrep -v "^[' '0-9a-zA-Z\t\n\v\f\r]*$|^[ ]*\[[A-Z].*\_*[A-Z]*=*[0-9]*\][ ]*$" SSPR.240, which gives an output as:

0010002$%!003000040000000010100
$%^&
```

However it is not considering the line:

```
[TXT_ID=2$@]
```

How can I modify my `egrep` statement?

Comment: Why is `[TXT]` not junk?

Comment: @kev The requirement of my file is such. I have some contexts defined under `[]`. The contexts can be two types `[Context=val]` or `[Context]`. `[TXT]` is a valid context.

Comment: @Druzion: by default grep doesn't support `\s` but you can use the POSIX character class: `[:space:]`

Comment: try this : `^[ ]*([a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*|\[[_a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]*(=[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]+)?\])[ ]*$`

Comment: @blackSmith Works fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
 egrep -v '^([[:space:]]*\[[[:alnum:]_]+=?[[:alnum:]_]*][[:space:]]*|[[:alnum:][:space:]_]*)$' file
```

Comment: This takes [TXT] as a line with junk character

Comment: This will accept `[TXT=]` as valid, which I think is not the intention of the OP although it's not in his samples.

Comment: @blackSmith: `[TXT=]` doesn't hurt me (a parameter with an empty value), that's why. I will not make more assumptions about what the OP want to allow or not.